FixedColumn Not Functioning in DataTables
I am a total noob when it comes to web design and would like to create a datatable with a fixed (frozen) left two columns.  I am reading in my data successfully from a JSON file and the information is displayed successfully.  However, when I try to set the columns to fixed, it just doesn't happen.
Below is a test example from my html file.  My input into JSFiddle works just fine, but the fixed columns are not rendering at all on my website.
I am using Hugo as my framework for my website, so if information from other files is needed, please let me know.  The code snippet below is from a partial that gets called.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fixed Columns Example</title>


    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.0/css/dataTables.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-2.1.0/fc-5.0.1/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        table {
            width: 20%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011-07-25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>8422</td>
                <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009-01-12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td>1562</td>
                <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
           
        </tbody>
    </table>



    <!-- jQuery first -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTables JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-2.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FixedColumns JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-2.1.0/fc-5.0.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Initialize DataTable with FixedColumns
            $('#example').DataTable({
                scrollX: true,
                scrollY: '400px',
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging: false,
                fixedColumns: {
                    left: 1 // Number of columns to fix
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


I solved it!  Updated the baseof.html datatable/fixedcolumn links to the newest versions.  Had no clue that's where it was taking it from.  Took way too long to figure this out.
